# Why does Python throw an error when I read a string out of a particular column of a csv file and try to parse it into a floating point number?

Tags: python, string, csv, floating-point, exponential

I am using the following python code to read numbers out of the csv file:

```
with open('file.csv') as p:
     rows = csv.reader(p)
     for row in rows:
         numbers = float(row[3])
```

I understand that although the csv file contains numbers, they are read as strings. Initially I would just parse the string into a float, but in this case when I try to do this Python throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/path/file.py", line 6, in <module>
    numbers = float(row[3])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: RVAL
```

The column in the csv file that the code reads from contains around 50,000 pseudo-random numbers all between 0 and 1. A handful of these numbers are so small that they're in exponential form in the file, e.g. 0.09932E-05. I suspect that this could be the cause of the problem, but I noticed that even when read and printed as a string the smaller numbers like 0.09932E-05 come with all the full original decimal places intact. This makes me unsure.

Is this likely to be the cause or is there another reason I'm missing?

How should I tackle the underlying cause of the problem? I require the numbers to be parsed from strings to floats/decimals so that I may put them in an array and order them numerically. I obviously cannot do this while they remain as strings.

EDIT:

It is clear that "RVAL" is what is causing the problem and for some reason I missed this. I suppose this demonstrates the need for a developer to look at the obvious before searching deeper and asking on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Try to `print row[3]`, you will see that at least once you get the string `RVAL` as shown in the error you have provided, which deems `float('RVAL')` to fail.

Comment: I've just noticed this after banging my head on the wall for an hour and failing to see the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

That particular row had the text `RVAL` in that column.

You can confirm this by modifying your code to handle the error:

```
try:
    numbers = float(row[3])
except ValueError, err:
    print("Failed while trying to convert to float: '%s'" % row[3])
    raise
```

Answer (score 1):

Skip what is presumably your header row

```
with open('file.csv') as p:
     rows = csv.reader(p)
     for row in rows[1:]
         numbers = float(row[3])
```